# CGPaths are always being drawn behind sublayer

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I was drawing a background image in the Draw method with several paths (`CGPath`) over it.
 To avoid drawing the background image every time a `setNeedDisplay` is called (when a path changes), I've created a layer with the `content = background image`.

This layer is added when the background image is set:

`Layer.InsertSublayer(backgroundLayer, 0);`

And the paths are drawn in the Draw method:

```
   public override void Draw(RectangleF rect)
   {
    base.Draw(rect);
    using (CGContext context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext())
    {
      CGPath path = new CGPath();
      ...
      context.DrawPath(CGPathDrawingMode.FillStroke);  
    }
   }
```

It seems that the drawing of the paths is being made in the "main" `Layer`, that is the `superlayer` of the background layer that I create (this is my assumption, don't know for sure).

Is it possible to draw the shapes in a different Layer (this way I could add a second layer to the superlayer and change the sublayer zposition)?

Thanks for your help,

L. Pinho

Comment: I need a little more information than this.  It looks like there is some confusion between UIKit UIView and CGAnimation's CALayer.  First, the content property, is "backgroundImage" a CGImage or a UIImage?  If it is a UIImage then that is the first problem.  The content needs to be a CGImage.  Also, you are using CGContext in the UIView's draw method.  Did you intend to make a CALayer or a UIView?  You don't necessarily need a second layer to change the zPosition.  Although it would make everything cleaner.

Comment: Hi Jan, I'm using a CALayer that I add to the self.Layer, at this time I'm using a UIImage to set the content (I will change to CGImage). Yes, I'm using the Draw method of the UIView to get the CGContext to draw the paths. I want to use a 2nd layer to avoid redrawing the background image every time I change the paths drawn over it. Hope you can help me.